# How to define a constructor in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to pass an object to a function that expects a class (i.e. a constructor function).

So I wrapped my object in an inline function that returns it.  But what do I set the definition of the function to?  I'm getting the error below, that the compiler expects the 'new' keyword, which I don't know how to add:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
kernel.bind<IPeachHelper>('IPeachHelper').to( (...args: any[]): IPeachHelper => { return _peachHelper} );
```

and the error:

```
Argument of type '(...args: any[]) => IPeachHelper' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new (...args: any[]) => IPeachHelper'.
```

Comment: Your question lacks needed information. For example: what's `IPeaceHelper`?  Also, while pictures are nice and all, the link may break in time, please also add the actual code to the question, and provide the all of the relevant code/info

Comment: Thanks, I've added the code as well as the picture. But I think I've given enough information - it's a generic question on how to pass an object instead of a class.

Comment: Pass the `_peachHelper` class instead of the instance (which is wrapped in a function)